# Why hardended xpub key cannot generate child public key?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

I'm trying to understand bip32 hardened mechanism, but I'm confused about it.

I got xpubKey from [this site](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/), and what I'm trying to do is demonstrate failure when trying to generate child pubkey from hardened xpubkey.

Here's my test details.

- network : bitcoin testnet
- mnemonic : dash axis fat pilot truly river guitar sea tonight popular type ill inmate quote upset
- parent path : m/44'
- parent xpubKey : tpubDA4h4NTsxqEXATU9dPS22ZVuBHd2jVketkP8RNhBZ6fMhW9WuMhrjf37qNmfmLQZoFreLmHf9LsTnvW2eJYx1fkzo7vVxsf7bKVixz2FjGw
- target child path : m/44'/0 (non regular, just for test)

and I wrote some js code, and I assumed to fail, but succeeded.

```
const bitcoinjs = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

const xpubKey = 'tpubDA4h4NTsxqEXATU9dPS22ZVuBHd2jVk...';

const parentNode = bitcoinjs.bip32.fromBase58(xpubKey, bitcoinjs.networks.testnet);

////////
// I THOUGHT BELOW WILL FAIL!
//////// 

// trying to get m/44'/0
const derived = parentNode.derive(0);

// result was valid public key for m/44'/0
console.log(derived.publicKey);
```

In my thought, if I have a valid xpubKey(hardened or not), means that I have a valid chain code and public key for current node (means that I can derive children).

So what's meaning of

> Hardened public keys cannot derive any children?

FYI, I quoted that in [this video (20:24)](https://youtu.be/OVvue2dXkJo?t=1224).

Answer (score 2):

Non-hardened parents effectively use the public key to derive their children, where hardened parents derive their children from the private key.

The derivation of a child private key from a non-hardened parent private key `k` uses the following hash function:

```
HMAC-SHA512(chainCode, point(k) || i)
```

We know that `K = point(k)`, where `K` is the parent public key. Thus, if we only know `K` and not necessarily `k`, we are still able to derive the child key by replacing `point(k)` with `K`, and follow the regular process.

With hardened private keys, the hashing is done differently:

```
HMAC-SHA512(chainCode, 0x00 || k || i)
```

Here you can see that there is no possible way that you could compute this hmac without knowing `k`. Just knowing the public key `K` will not help.

---

It looks as though you need to use the `deriveHardened` function in bitcoinjs rather than plain `derive`.

Comment: The even shorter answer is that you cannot derive hardened public keys from xpubs, because hardening is specifically designed to make exactly that impossible.